# How to query data for CQWP?

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part

I have added the CQWP successfully to the web part page programmatically.
Now I want to query data for that web part i.e. I want to display the title of the file from the document library.

My code is:

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://........");       

SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;          

web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

SPLimitedWebPartManager webParts = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("SiteAssets/webparts.aspx", System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);

 ContentByQueryWebPart wp = new ContentByQueryWebPart();
 wp.Title = "My web part using OM";

 wp.ListUrl = web.Url + "/Sample Docs";
wp.ListName = "Sample Docs";            
wp.ItemXslLink = web.Url + "/Style Library/ItemStyle.xsl";
wp.CommonViewFields = "Title,Text";
webParts.AddWebPart(wp, "Right", 0);
webParts.SaveChanges(wp);
web.Update();
Console.WriteLine("Web part added successfully");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Document Library is in the root site with name Sample Docs.

I am getting the output like:

[image]

How to query data? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `QueryOverride` property of `ContentByQueryWebPart` class. Create the desired query by a tool like CAML query builder and assign it to `QueryOverride`

**EDIT**

For example, you can write query like this:

```
wp.QueryOverride= "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/>" +
    "<Value Type='Text'>Completed</Value></Eq></Where>";
```

Comment: Can you please post any reference link or suggestion if any?
Because I am totally new to this concept..

Comment: `wp.Title = "My web part using OM";
                wp.ListUrl = web.Url + "/Sample Docs";
                wp.ListName = "Sample Docs";
                wp.XslLink = web.Url + "/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ItemStyle.xsl";
                wp.QueryOverride = "<where> <Eq> <FileLeafRef Name='Title' /> <Value Type='Text'/></Eq></Where>";
                webParts.AddWebPart(wp, "Right", 0);
                webParts.SaveChanges(wp);
                web.Update();`

Though I am getting the error that there is a problem with query.

Comment: "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/><Value Type='File'>" + docname + "</Value></Eq></Where>" See this for reference http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35571/caml-query-to-get-listitem-by-name-field

Comment: I wrote the line as per your suggestion i.e.
`<where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/><Value Type='File'>example1</Value></Eq></Where>` still I am getting error.

Comment: One more thing is that if I provide the document name in the query then what to do to get all document names from library?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981241%28v=office.14%29.aspx) out, it gives a good oversight of the posibilities and how to use the CQWP correctly. I hope this will help a bit.

Comment: I went through the article and changed the lines of code i.e.,
`wp.QueryOverride = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/><Value Type='File'></Value></Eq></Where>";
                wp.ListsOverride = @"<Lists> <List ID='{EFF50FAD-F899-4E26-A9A4-1B40AEDFC9BE}'/> </Lists>";`
but I am getting error.

Answer (score 0):

there is another idea to do this which is adding your CQWP using the portal UI then export the webpart after that you can import the exported web part into any page using [SPLimitedWebPartManager.ImportWebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.splimitedwebpartmanager.importwebpart.aspx)
 and here is an example to this 
http://avinash-moss-expert.blogspot.com/2010/08/add-web-part-programmatically-using.html